# Customer synchronization from Cq5 to Hybris

Tags: aem, sap-commerce-cloud

I am very new to CQ5 and Hybris. I am implementing a scenario where a Customer registers in CQ5 frontend website and the details are subsequently saved in Hybris as well as CQ5. 
I am using CQ5.6.1, Hybris 5.0.4, CQ Hybris Content 5.6.100 packages.

Could someone help me what steps should I follow to implement the scenario? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Varada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in order to achieve the connection between CQ5 and hybris you'll need to implement something called *Omni Commerce Connect*, which is basically achieved by extending hybris' *ycommercewebservices* extension.

That way you have a bunch of Web Service endpoints on your hybris tier ready to be consumed by integrating clients, including endpoints to create and update customer accounts in hybris.

My CQ5 is a bit rusty, but from what I remember we had something called a ProfileSynchronizer that you had to register as an Event Handler or something on CQ. This ProfileSynchronizer would then be triggered by CQ5 whenever a user account was created or updated and in this synchronizer you'll have to write the appropriate code to call the hybris endpoint which updates user accounts in hybris.

Hopefully this can get you started.